# Get the name of file as parameter in a batch application

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have created a batch file that passes some arguments to run a jar file.
I want that when I drag a jar file to it, then it should take that as an argument. But when I do it, it only runs the batch file and does not take the file as an argument. Please help me.

Comment: The file name as an argument? (its in `%1` : `@echo the file name dropped on me is %1`) or the contents of the text file?

Comment: Please show us the batch file.

Comment: Alex, I actually want the full file path. eg: "C:\PSingh\Batch\test.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is :

```
java -jar %1
```

As **Alex K.** has said, `%1` is the first operator provided to the batch file.

`%1` has the value of the file-name when a file is dragged to the batch-file.